# Amber framework : url_for in rails?

Tags: crystal-lang, amber-framework

Is there something like `url_for` in rails to implement:

`url_for controller: CONTROLLER, action: ACTION, arg_1: ARG1, arg_2: ARG2` generates link `/CONTROLLER_PATH/ACTION?arg_1:ARG1&arg_2:ARG2`?

Comment: May want to ask the amber people...

Comment: there was a bit of discussion here: https://github.com/amberframework/amber/pull/221/files/5f601d3a4ea9edc999baead30e73e411d3586cb9